# Pandas GroupBy without MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

If I set the following DF and dictionary (pandas 0.22.0):

```
kwargs = {
  'index': ['11-1000', '11-1001', '11-1002'],
  'data': np.random.randint(5, size=(3,2)),
  'columns': ['A', 'B']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(**kwargs)

df         A  B
>> 11-1000 2  1
>> 11-1001 1  4
>> 11-1002 2  3
```

and

```
by = {'11-1001': '11-1000', '11-1002': '11-1000'}
```

and want to group by this dictionary, the result seems incorrect:

```
df.groupby(by=by, level=0).get_group('11-1000')
>>         A B
>> 11-1000 2 1
```

when I'm expecting something like

```
>>         A  B
>> 11-1001 1  4
>> 11-1002 2  3
```

If I have a MultIndex to start with, though:

```
df = df.set_index('A", append=True)
df
>>            B
>>         A
>> 11-1000 2  1
>> 11-1001 1  4
>> 11-1002 2  3
```

then it seems like groupby gives me what I want:

```
df.groupby(by=by, level=0).get_group('11-1000')
>>            B
>>         A
>> 11-1001 1  4
>> 11-1002 2  3
```

Any thoughts on this? I almost always use groupby with a MultiIndex, so I've not seen this behavior before and not sure if it's normal. How can I get my desired behavior without a MultiIndex?

Comment: I believe not passing anything for the `level` argument (or `level=None`) gets the behavior you want. I don't know if the behavior of `level` is well-defined without a MultiIndex

Comment: @VictorChubukov turn it into a answer :-)

Comment: @VictorChubukov That...makes complete sense and works for me. Thank you!

Edit: if you submit a formal answer I'll accept it. I guess I can't accept comments as answers..kind of new to actually using SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the behavior of the `level` parameter is not particularly well-defined without a MultiIndex.

Passing `level=None` (which is the default) gets the behavior you want.